# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET PushStreamContent

Tags: connection-reset, pushstreamcontent

I´m trying to stream a video using PushStreamContent, but some seconds after the video starts playing the browser gives me a net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET ( Error )

Frontend : using  tag to call a webapi method that uses a action that sends a buffer with parts of a video file

Hope that i could explain my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework Core, you may have a looping object graph. Since EF Core does not support lazy loading, your serializer might be stuck in an infinite loop trying to serialize your object graph.

Replace the `services.AddMvc()` line in your Startup.cs with this:

```
            services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```